# MS Access Report using VBA with double Detail? Possible?

Tags: vba, ms-access, reporting

**Background:**

I am currently trying to understand how reports work in access since I'm new to the whole reporting scene. 
I have worked out how to create a report that is based on a table. - That's fine.
But trying to make it more customizable to what I need is proving to be somewhat of a challenge.

**Problem:**

The report I am creating is using data that requires two lines of detail.
To explain better:

The ****first line**** in the report should show the general overview of a transaction that is made like an Invoice transaction....

Then ****underneath**** I want a line that uses slightly smaller text to show the details of the Invoice transaction.. information such as the Payment that paid the Invoice displayed above.

I have managed to get it to show kind of... but its show large gaps probably because of the way I have it placed in the report design view.

**In the Report Design:**

All in the detail section of the report - I have the first line bound to a table and then immediately below another line that is bound to the same table but using different data.

**Question:**

Is what I am trying to achieve possible? Is there something in Access that can handle this?

Hope my question is clear.

Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify: When you say that the second line in the Detail band is "bound to the same table but using different data", do you mean that those controls use different *fields* from the same *record* (row) in the table as the controls (fields) in the first line?

Comment: This sounds like you might just want a sub-report

Comment: Yes @GordThompson - I have the first line in the detail bound to one set of fields then the second line bound to another set of fields in a table - It almost works but there are just random large gaps between the rows on display. I have pulled the footer part right up to the second row... so not sure why there are blank spaces :(

Comment: @Scotch - I had a look and tried the subform method... certainly got rid of my large blank spaces. but now the data is not pulling in correctly - it's repeating line... can you explain how the subform is related to the main form is, is there a way for me to code a link for the form so that it knows what load in each section of the subform... Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would make your report based off a query, not a table; as your data grows the report will become less managable based on a table.

Create a query that contains just the data that you need and then create the appropriate header; for example if you have a transaction that was paid by multiple invoices (or by one, if you just want the report to format for you) then you would group by the unique identifier for the transaction, this creates an area 'Transaction Header' where you put all the fields specific to the transaction (transaction id, transaction date etc). Then underneath in the 'Detail' section you put all the fields specific to the invoices (invoice number, invoice date, invoice amount etc). The result will be one line for the transaction and then one line for each invoice. You can add subsequent groupings are required and format the detail section to be a smaller text etc as you require.

If you can't get all the data you need into one query or there would be conflicting groupings then you will need to use subforms as Scotch suggests.

The large gaps you mention are probably because you need to reduce the height of your detail section; your controls should generally form one horizontal line and the make the detail section just larger than this.

Hope this helps, if not I would need more info on what you are trying to put in the report.

Comment: I think you are completely correct with the query solution. I am just using the table as a view to what is being pulled into the report and how it is being shown from a visual perspective. Should be quite easy to transfer my VBA code into the queries after it works...

Comment: I already put the footer line right up the the second row of my report in the design view. but it i'm not sure whether the gaps are appearing because in some cases i have multiple second row lines with just one first row line... does this make sense? I hope i'm not confusing you!

Comment: To explain further - we can use a simple Invoice example: I have three columns - Col1 - "Transaction code" = **"SI"**, Col2 - "Account ID" = **"AER001"**, Col3 - "Amount" - **"200"**.......So the Invoice will have a detail line of the Sales Receipt that paid the Invoice..... and if it was the other way round... looking at the Sales Receipt... you would see the detail of all the Invoices that the Sales Receipt Paid...